# Export filenames in Lightroom 3

Tags: lightroom, filenames

I export images from Lightroom to PhotoShelter using the Pact Software plugin. I would dearly like to sort my files in my PhotoShelter galleries in the following order:

- rating (descending)
- time (ascending)

The sorting is ultimately done by PhotoShelter, which has the ability to sort by date, filename, or a custom order defined by dragging images around.

So I am looking for a clever way to create a filename that can be sorted Z-A to give the ordering I require. Currently I use {Rating}-{Date}-{Filename} and live with the reverse date order after I've sorted it on filename (descending.)

I don't want to introduce an intermediate step, rather to keep going directly from Lightroom to PhotoShelter. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a thought, but why ascending time? Surely descending rating and descending time would mean your best and latest images are at the top, which seems preferable so repeat visitors see new stuff immediately.

Comment: I agree that way is best for some collections like portfolios but I find for event photography it looks a bit better to have the rating subsections in order of ascending time.

Comment: Comments on why this was downvoted would be interesting, is it not the right subject matter for this site?

Answer (score 1):

I like a challenge!

The only way I can find of doing this is as follows:

1. Sort your collection by Rating, in Z-A order.
2. Now export with a naming template something like this:

   **{Image # (0001)»}-{Date (YYYYMMDD)»}-{Filename»}**

That should result in exactly what you're after.

Comment: That is almost perfect .. but if you modify and re-export single files later, your image sequence will be different - I think. Will check..

Comment: Yes, you're right. I forgot about that but it's caught me out many times in the past. :(